# 「呆れる」とはどういう意味ですか？

Tags: meaning, words, nuances

呆れるとはどういう意味か今一つわからないのです。goo辞書で調べると、「あまりに意外なことに驚く」というのが出てきますが、今まで見てきた例を考え合わせてみると、やはり納得がいかないところが残っています。特に、「呆れる」には必ず「驚き」の要素が入っていますか？「ショック」「衝撃」と同じくらい、爆発的な印象がありますか？

そして、三つの例について聞かせてください。

①「同じ過ちを繰り返す自分に呆れた」

- これは「同じ過ちを繰り返す自分に驚いた」に言い換えられますか？自分に期待をなくしたり、失望したりするのは、普通はぱっと成り果てるものではなく、過ちを重ねるほどに成り果てる、段階的な過程ですよね。でしたら「驚く」というより、「うんざりする」「飽きる」という方が正確なのではないでしょうか。

② 漫画のシーンですが、本を大好きなキャラクターが、たいてい本を好きでない友達に好きな本を見つけたよ！と言われます。うきうきしながら本の名前を聞くと、くだらない本の名前が出てきて、がっかりした顔をしてしまいます。すると、「呆れただろう！子どもっぽいって！」と言われてしまい、必死に「いえいえ、そんなことは思ってない！」と否定しようとします。

- 個人的な解釈ではありますが、そのキャラクターの顔からみたら、驚くのではなく、がっかりしているとしか思えません。ポカンとした顔でもキョトンとした顔でもなく、ただ元気をなくした顔だけですし。でしたらその友達は、「驚いた」の意味で「呆れただろう！」と責め、勘違いしたわけですか？コメディーなので、当たったからこそ焦って否定しようとしていることで、面白みが出てくるわけだと思いますが、勘違いにすぎないのでしょうか。または、「呆れる」が「がっかり」の意味にもなっているのでしょうか。

③ また漫画のシーンですが、あるキャラクターが友達に誕生日プレゼントを送ると、顔が嬉しそうに見えないので、「呆れた？」と聞きます。それで友達が「いえいえ！びっくりしただけだ！」と否定します。

- これは大体わかりますが、一応確認したいです。この「呆れた？」は「Are you shocked?」と捉えればいいですか。もしくは、「いやなの？」「Do you not like it?」のような意味になっていますか。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「あきれる」には、多少の驚きや意外に思う気持ちは含まれていますが、爆発的な衝撃というニュアンスはありません。溜め息が出そうな気持ちや、[この絵文字 ()](https://emojipedia.org/shrug/)みたいな感じも「あきれる」で表現できます。

明鏡国語辞典で「あきれる」を引くと、「物事の異常さや**言動の非常識さ**などに驚いてとまどいを感じる」という定義になっており、「ふつう驚きとともに**非難や愛想づかしの意**がこもる」という注釈がついています。つまり、単に「驚いた」という気持ちだけではなく「非常識だ」「バカだ」という気持ちが普通は入っているということです。文脈によっては驚きの意味がほとんどなく、「バカだ、どうしようもない」という意味の方が中心になることもあると思います。あなたの挙げた3つの例はいずれも、「驚いた」よりも「なんてバカなんだろう」という気持ちの方が中心となっている例だと思います。

Answer (score 5):

まず、この文脈での「驚く」は、surprised というよりも、disappointed に近い意味で使われています。
ですので、「ショック」「衝撃」のような、爆発的な印象はあまりありません。

①「同じ過ちを繰り返す自分に呆れた」

これを「同じ過ちを繰り返す自分に驚いた」と言い換えるのは可能です。
「うんざりした」も使えると思います。ですが「飽きた」は使いません。
この使い分けを考える場合、この文章に「後悔している」といった意味も含まれていると考えると分かりやすいかもしれません。

②「呆れただろう！子どもっぽいって！」

これも「呆れる」が「がっかり」を意味していると考えて問題ありません。
また「いえいえ、そんなことは思ってない！」と否定しているのは、主に「子どもっぽい」の部分かと思います。
（特に女性が男性に対して発言する場合）子供っぽさはマイナスのイメージとして捉えられることが多いので、それを慌てて否定するという流れは、結構多く出てくるかと思います。

③プレゼントを渡した時に「呆れた？」

この場合「呆れた？」はあまり使わないと思いますが、意味は「いやなの？」「Do you not like it?」の方が近いかと思います。

これは「（プレゼント選びのセンスに）呆れた？」⇒「気に入らなかった？」（いやなの？）という2段階で解釈するといいかと思います。

本来は辞書で、この説明に該当するものを提示した方がよいのかもしれませんが、割愛させていただきます。

Comment: 三つの例をそれぞれ詳しく解説していただきありがとうございます。narutoさんの回答をベストアンサーにいたしましたけれど、この回答も、両方をベストアンサーにできないことを悔やむぐらい参考になりました。

Comment: @lightweaver コメントありがとうございます。1つの単語でも、辞書によって色々な表現や説明があるように、ベストと思える回答が複数あってもよいと思います。